Telegram Bot Creating & Storing Private Keys
So im building a bot for buying sol tokens, and i will be creating wallets for users in the bot something like temporary wallets, which means i have to store private keys, now telegram bot doesnt allow me to store on the users device so what is my best option? Pleae help
